# Arcgis explained?

Tags: gis, arcgis

I want to look into ArcGis, and I cant get my head around where it fits in.

I have used the Google Maps API to create some simple maps with makers, Overlays, Listeners etc.

I have recently started looking at PostGIS, and i fully understand that, it enhances Postgres with additional data types and functions for drawing polygons and mapping areas. Great!

What I dont understand is where ArcGIS fits in?

What does it do? why would you use it.

I have a large db of addresses.

Comment: Qgis is a free alternative to ArcGis if you wanted to investigate further yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand google maps API and postGIS then you really have no need for ArcGIS. Download QGIS and use it in conjunction with POSTGIS http://www.qgis.org/
ARCGIS is just unnecessary that's why it doesn't make sense to you (and rightfully so).

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, it comes down to whether you are happier having a big software stack where everything is designed to work together or whether you are happier doing a bit of SQL, and/or Javascript and Python coding (these are the big players in open source GIS), and generally piecing bits together yourself. ESRI, the makers of the ArcGIS family (which includes desktop, server and web based technologies) is essentially the Microsoft of the GIS world -- the big player, whose products are designed to work very well with each other, but are sometimes a bit tardy when it comes to standards compliance or interaction with 3rd party software.

On the open source side, Postgis, which essentially provides a spatial type extension to Postgres plus many spatial functions, is really an amalgam of various packages: GEOS, which provides many of the spatial predicate functions, Proj4j which does coordinate system conversion and GDAL which provides a lot of glue functions. Recently Postgis has added native support for raster, 3d and topology functions, along with the long existing vector functions, which means that amazingly sophisticated GIS analysis can be performed directly at the database level by chaining together SQL functions.

As has been suggested above QuantumGIS (generally known as QGIS) provides most of the functionality of ArcGIS desktop, for those wanting to go that route. Javascript libraries, such as the OpenLayers or Leaflet (there are many others) can be used to visualize the results of Postgis queries. In addition, there are tools such as Geoserver (Java serlvet based) which allow you to serve up data held either in Postgres/Postgis tables or ESRI shp files in common formats such as WMS, WFS and WMTS, acting as a bridge between client and server.

The final decision is often as much political as technical. If you work for a large utility company or local government, for example, support contracts and industry norms are likely to outweight budgetary constraints. If you are working for a small startup and have people who are happy working at the command line, you will likely get much better value for money from the open source stack.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are asking about ArcMap  which is ESRI's desktop GIS application.  The application is an extremely powerful cartographic production and analytic tool that allows the user to perform complex spatial operations.  ArcMap also provides a graphical user interface that allows users to edit geometry supporting complex typologies that model real world phenomenon.  The application also supports a wide range of raster analysis that is commonly used for remote sensing.

Some examples of how you could use ArcGIS with your database of addresses:

1. You can use it to compare addresses to census data and better understand customers.
2. Generate heat maps of statistically significant clusters.
3. Use network analysis tools to identify closest facilities or route you to the addresses in the most efficient order.
4. Find what types of features your data falls within (ie City council districts, fire districts, states, etc) and update your data with that information.

These are just a few things you could do with ArcGIS. In short, this tool allows you to view and analyze your data in a spatial context versus the relational approach you seem to be taking now.

Answer (score 2):

ESRI's ArcGIS is very powerful and has TONS of customization options through their ArcObjects API as well as a new way to add your own custom tools and button commands through a framework they call Add-ins.  You can even use Python to create a very simple (code-wise) tool that lets a user click a button and, for example, return a selection on the map of all the telephone poles that are within 50 feet of a tree line.  They could then just export this set of pole features as a tabular data report for a tree trimming crew to visit each pole to see if they need to trim back the vegetation.  You can also use their ArcGIS Runtime to build a completely custom tool that runs from a USB thumb drive with zero install with only the parts and pieces you create like a Map, Table of contents, and a custom toolbar that has only the buttons and tools you need specific for that application.  I've seen a gas utility inspection application written this way that only had the map and three buttons for them to use on an iPad or Android tablet.  The options with ArcGIS are very near to endless and they keep updating it all constantly.

My day job is customizing ArcGIS to fit gas, water, and power utilities' needs to match their business workflow.  I have been working with ArcGIS since 2004.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer:  It lets you use MAPS to analyze and store data in a database, where said data has some sort of 'location' attribute on a surface or in 3D space.

Here's a quick example:  "Return all of the parcels in Smith County that are within 1000 feet of a school and display them in red on a map."

Answer (score 1):

If I had to answer in one sentence it would be like: if you just want to show where is something on the map (and some basic data with it) use Google Maps API but if you want to analyze, query and understand your spatial data use ArcGIS.

ArcGIS is platform, containing Desktop, Server, Portal (spatial CMS) with various types of geodatabases supported. ArcGIS for Desktop is used for powerful spatial analysis, it includes more than 700 different tools that support strong spatial and alpha – numerical analysis. When we are talking about spatial analysis we can talk about different spatial overlays (simple example: where do wolves and foxes live), proximity analysis (factory to customer distances; protected area (buffer) around oil drill) and spatial statistics (finding patterns in space (and time), mapping clusters (hot/cold spots) and also, since database is in the background of every serious GIS you can use SQL to query your alpha-numerical (and spatial) data to make better decisions.

Mapping is also function of ArcGIS Desktop software – our brains can understand much better information when they are visualized, and also you can and should visualize results you obtained through analysis. Keep in mad that map is only visualization of the data in geodatabase (or shapefile).

ArcGIS Desktop is also used for data entry – with “heads up” editing, for example form orto-photo images for creating vectors with attributes.

Geodatabase management is also part of ArcGIS and geodatabases vary from file geodatabases to enterprise geodatabases which use SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 and other RDBMS systems. Single user file geodatabase supports one concurrent editor and has no storage limit, while enterprise databases provide multiuser editing, versioning, archiving and backup scenarios. Personal geodatabase is single user geodatabase using Microsoft Access for storing spatial data.

ArcGIS for Server provides different formats of spatial services containing spatial data (map) along with alpha-numerical information (if supported by format). Types of ArcGIS for Server services that can be published are: Mapping, WCS, WMS, Feature Access, Schematics, Mobile Data Access, Network Analysis, KML, WFS… ArcGIS for Server services are authored using ArcMap, served with Server (of course) and their URL links are used by developers who code from the scratch or used within Portal for ArcGIS web app templates which can be customized by developers if needed, or other, Silverlight of Flex Esri viewers.

Comment: `if you just want to show where is something on the map use Google Maps API but if you want to analyze, query and understand your spatial data use ArcGIS` NO, the world does not divide between GMaps and ArcGIS. It is not about brands, but about types of software.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you are already comfortable with PostGIS, you should be fine for any work with vectors. If you are working with raster data then I think that would be where ArcGIS would fit in. In ArcGIS you can run different types of statistics and filters on rasters where I don't think you can with PostGIS but I'm sure that will eventually be added.

One more thing, if you ever need to automate your PostGIS work, I would recommend using Python with the psycopg2 library.

Comment: Postgis has had an extremely impressive array of raster functions for some time now: http://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html They work seamlessly with the vector functions. And, yes, great call re psycopg2.